# Android: How do I bind each value of an ArrayList to a variable?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, foreach, imageview

I have an ArrayList that holds ImageViews:

```
ArrayList<ImageView> ivArray = new ArrayList<ImageView>();  
imgView1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView1);  
imgView2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView2);  
ivArray.add(imgView1);  
ivArray.add(imgView2);
```

I pass this ArrayList to my custom class so it can access each ImageView passed in.

```
CustomClass cClass = new CustomClass(ivArray);
```

How can I get each value from the passed in ArrayList in my custom class, and bind them to their own variable?
I was thinking something along the lines of using a foreach loop, like:

```
public class CustomClass() {
    public CustomClass(ArrayList<ImageView> ivArray) {
        for (ImageView iView : ivArray) {
            // Bind each ImageView
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the actual problem?

Comment: @mihail I need to be able to access each individual ImageView in a separate method so I can set their images to something.

Comment: you mean you need something like a class property that can be used in the whole CustomClass?

Comment: @mihail Not class properties, class objects, and I need to create as many as there are ImageViews in the passed in ArrayList and give them their own name.

Comment: you can't define separate variables in runtime, that's why there are `ArrayList`s and `HashMap`s . Check @Penna suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [HashMap](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)

```
 public class CustomClass{
        //Bind it to a string just for example
        private HashMap<String, ImageView> mMap = new HashMap<String, ImageView>();
        public CustomClass(ArrayList<ImageView> ivArray) {
            for (ImageView iView : ivArray) {
                mMap.put("SomeValue", iView);
            }
        }
        public ImageView getImageViewByString(String s){
            return mMap.get(s);
        }
    }
```

Comment: instead of String, I'd use `int` key for the HashMap and init it with `mMap.put(iView.getId(), iView);` and then the get method will look like `public ImageView getImageViewById(int id)`

Comment: @Dan_Pena at `private HashMap<String, ImageView> mMap = new HashMap<String, ImageView>;`, it gives the error "syntax error on token(s) misplaced construct(s)" for the `= new HashMap<String, ImageView> part`.

Comment: Fixed now, I forgot to add () after the instantiation

Comment: Thank you, HashMaps are something I'm not familiar with, so this is a good learning experience for me.